# Prove that the sequence diverges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, analysis, polynomials

I want to prove that the polynomial $P_{m}(n)=n^{m}+a_{m-1}n^{m-1}+ \cdots +a_{0}$ with $m \geq 1$, satisfies that $\lim_{n \to \infty} P_{m}(n)=+\infty$.

Then we want to see that for each $M>0$, There exists $N\in \mathbb{N}^{+}$ such that $a_{n}>M$ for all $n \geq N$.

Let any $M>0$ and consider

$$P_{m}(n)=n^{m}\left(1+\frac{a_{m-1}}{n}+\frac{a_{m-2}}{n^2}    +\cdots + \frac{a_{0}}{n^{m}} \right)$$

Since it is true that $\frac{1}{n^{m}}\leq \frac{1}{n}$ then $1+\cdots +\frac{a_{0}}{n^{m}} \geq 1+\cdots +\frac{a_{0}}{n}$

It follows that

$$P_{m}(n)\geq n^{m} \left(1+\frac{a_{m-1}+ \cdots +a_{0}}{n}  \right) $$

Here comes my doubt about how to find the $N$ that works for the proof, because we could start with the following

We want find $N$ such that if $n\geq N$ then $\left(1+\frac{a_{m-1}+ \cdots +a_{0}}{n}  \right) >1$ but it would not be a very optimal way, I think, to find such $N$.

Any suggestions? any help is welcome

Comment: Try the reverse triangle inequality: $|1+u|\geq1-|u|$.

Comment: It does not have to be optimal. Any result which shows what you want is good enough. Optimal comes later. Besides, do it in stages is better for your career. First you establish something and publish. Then you establish something better and publish again. Eventually you might get optimal or maybe not. In any case eventually you get tenure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since it is true that $\frac{1}{n^{m}}\leq \frac{1}{n}$ then $1+\cdots +\frac{a_{0}}{n^{m}} \geq 1+\cdots +\frac{a_{0}}{n}$

This is not true, because you don't know the sign for each $a_m$. Instead, you can do the following

$$\begin{align}P_{m}(n)&=n^{m}\left(1+\frac{a_{m-1}}{n}+\frac{a_{m-2}}{n^2}    +\cdots + \frac{a_{0}}{n^{m}} \right)\\
\\
&\ge n^{m}\left(1-\left|\frac{a_{m-1}}{n}\right|-\left|\frac{a_{m-2}}{n^2}\right|    -\cdots - \left|\frac{a_{0}}{n^{m}}\right| \right)\\
\\
&\ge n^{m}\left(1-\left|\frac{a_{m-1}}{n}\right|-\left|\frac{a_{m-2}}{n}\right|    -\cdots - \left|\frac{a_{0}}{n}\right| \right)\\
\\
&\ge n^{m}\left(1-\frac{m|A|}{n}\right)\end{align}$$

where $|A|=\max\{ |a_0|, |a_1|,\dots,|a_{m-1}|\}$

First, choose $N_1=2m|A|$, we have

$$P_m(n)\ge n^{m}\left(1-\frac{m|A|}{n}\right)\ge \frac{1}2n^m$$
Next, choose $N_2=(2M)^{1/m}$

Finally, take $N=\max(N_1, N_2)$, when $n>N$, you have
$$P_m(n)\ge n^{m}\left(1-\frac{m|A|}{n}\right)\ge \frac{1}2n^m>M$$

Comment: This works if the coefficients are all real. A little adjustment is necessary if one considers complex polynomials.

Comment: Yes, show $|P(z)|>M$

Comment: I appreciate your contribution, but I have a small doubt, the inequality $P_{m}(n)=n^{m}(1+\frac{a_{m-1}}{n}+\frac{a_{m-2}}{n^2}    +\cdots + \frac{a_{0}}{n^{m}})  \geq n^{m}\left(1-|\frac{a_{m-1}}{n}|-|\frac{a_{m-2}}{n^2}|    -\cdots - \left|\frac{a_{0}}{n^{m}}\right| \right)$ is guaranteed by the fact that $|1+a|\geq1−|a|$ ? I don't see it so clearly

Comment: @Wrloord It's just the [reverse triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality#Reverse_triangle_inequality)

Answer (score 1):

Following your train of thought, we only need to prove that for any given $M>0$, there exists some $N$ such that for all $n>N$, we have $P_m(n)>M.$

Let $S_m=|a_0|+\dots+|a_{m-1}|,N_0=2S_m,N_1=\sqrt[m]{2M}$ and $N=\max\{N_0,N_1\}$, then for any given $M>0$ and $n>N$,
\begin{align}
P_m(n) &\geq n^m\left(1-\frac{S_m}{n}\right)\\
&> n^m\left(1-\frac{1}{2}\right)\\
&=\frac{n^m}{2}\\
&>M.
\end{align}

Comment: Let $P_2 (n) = n^2  - n + 1$. Then you claim (in your first inequality) that $P_2 (n) \ge n^2$ for sufficiently large $n$. This is not true. Can you see what your mistake is?

Comment: Sorry for this mistake, I just copy the author's derivation without checking. I have revised the answer.